# Dynamic changes in a form: call to server or not?

Tags: php

I have a form with a select with 2 options. Depending on the selected value it shows or hide a checkbox,

My question: should I did an ajax call to add/remove that checkbox, or should I just show/hide it just using javascript?

Comment: Whats the concrete problem?

Comment: @KingCrunch I just don't know what is the proper way..

Comment: Proper way for what? If hiding checkbox is that essential, just check it on the server side, after the form is submitted, there's no need for an extra ajax call check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just show or hide it with Javascript when the select is changed. You shouldn't do an ajax call  unless you need a server side computation or the server needs to know about the change for any reason.